# code multiple columns based on lists and dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe in Pandas

```
 OfferPreference_A  OfferPreference_B   OfferPreference_C   
            A          B                  A                  
            B          C                  C                 
            C          S                  G
```

I have the following dictionary of unique values under all the columns

```
  dict1={A:1, B:2, C:3, S:4, G:5, D:6}
```

I also have a list of the columnames

```
  columnlist=['OfferPreference_A', 'OfferPreference_B', 'OfferPreference_C']
```

I Am trying to get the following table as the output

```
    OfferPreference_A   OfferPreference_B   OfferPreference_C   
               1           2                  1                  
               2           3                 3                  
               3           4                  5
```

How do I do this.

Comment: Waht happen if value not match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` for this like shown below, assuming the values will match always

```
for col in columnlist:
    df[col] = df[col].map(dict1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
#if value not match get NaN
df = df[columnlist].applymap(dict1.get)
```

Or:

```
#if value not match get original value
df = df[columnlist].replace(dict1)
```

Or:

```
#if value not match get NaN
df = df[columnlist].stack().map(dict1).unstack()
```

---

```
print (df)
   OfferPreference_A  OfferPreference_B  OfferPreference_C
0                  1                  2                  1
1                  2                  3                  3
2                  3                  4                  5
```